# Loading an outbuffer to a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to load the output buffer into a string using javascript ?

for example in php

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>

hello world !

<?php $string = ob_get_contents(); ?>
```

Comment: add some more detail , what you mean output butter?

Comment: mmmmmmmmmmmm, output butter ...

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific, code is tested!

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
hello world !
<?php $string = ob_get_contents(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var MyJSStringVar = "<? echo trim($string)?>";
console.log(MyJSStringVar);
alert(MyJSStringVar);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running PHP 5.2 or above, you can call `json_encode()` to automatically escape the string properly for JavaScript.

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>

hello world !

<?php $string = ob_get_contents(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var theString = <?php echo json_encode($string); ?>;
</script>
```

For PHP 5.1 or below, you can use a compatibility library, like [jsonwrapper](http://www.boutell.com/scripts/jsonwrapper.html), that adds the `json_encode` function for you.